# In a two columns document, a long table in one column offsets text in the other column

Tags: tables, floats, two-column

I have a table that is almost as tall as the text height in a document with two columns. The problem is that the text in the adjacent column is shifted downwards until the end of the caption of the table:

[image]

Here is a reproducible example, using [this template (direct link)](https://static.primary.prod.gcms.the-infra.com/static/site/bioinformatics/document/cabios-template.zip?node=0dd78a73d16bf6a2b799&version=23584:a9838eca83b4c0bcf4a3):

```
\documentclass{bioinfo}
\copyrightyear{2020} \pubyear{2020}
\access{Advance Access Publication Date: Day Month Year}
\appnotes{Manuscript Category}
\usepackage{lipsum,tabularx,expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_eq:NN \Repeat \prg_replicate:nn
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\firstpage{1}
\subtitle{Subject Section}
\title[short title]{full title}
\author[AAA]{AAA$^*$}
\address{BBB}
\corresp{$^\ast$To whom correspondence should be addressed.}
\history{Received on XXXXX; revised on XXXXX; accepted on XXXXX}
\editor{Associate Editor: XXXXXXX}
\abstract{\textbf{Motivation:} \lipsum[1] \\ \textbf{Results:} \lipsum[2]}

\maketitle

\begin{figure*}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=0.2\textheight]{example-image-a}
\caption{\lipsum[1]}
\end{figure*}

\section*{Introduction}
\lipsum[1-5]

\begin{table}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{cXr}
\hline \\
\Repeat{40}{aaa & bbb & ccc \\}
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\caption{\lipsum[1]}
\end{table}

\Repeat{3}{
\section*{sec}
\subsection*{sub}
\lipsum[1] \begin{equation}a=b+c\end{equation}
\lipsum[1] \begin{equation}a=b+c\end{equation}
\lipsum[1] \begin{equation}a=b+c\end{equation}
\lipsum[1] \begin{equation}a=b+c\end{equation}
}
\end{document}
```

How can I have text in the right column? I would also accept a solution where the left column only contains the table, but I do not want to make the table span both columns.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please let us know which document class you employ (or is that sensitive information as well?), and please indicate which tools you use to create the table. E.g., do you employ a `table` or `table*` environment? Do you employ a `tabular` environment? (Judging from the blurred screenshot, I would suspect that you're a `table*` environment even though a `table` environment may be more appropriate.) Have you tried breaking the long table into two or three shorter tables?

Comment: @Mico @DavidCarlisle thank you for your comments, I managed to make create an example. I do not want to use a `table*`, though

Comment: @BlackBear we were not suggesting you use `table*` to fix the problem, we were guessing (incorrectly) that you had used `table*` to cause the problem. Thanks for the example, I'll look...

Comment: Thanks for posting some example code. Unfortunately, it does *not* reproduce the issue you say you're encountering -- at least not on my system (MacTeX2019). What gives?

Comment: sorry ignore earlier comment I can reproduce with the class file in that zip,

Comment: @Mico it works on overleaf, here's an editable link: https://www.overleaf.com/1787875484jgpsjmwmggdc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The zip file contains ancient (and now incompatible) versions of several standard packages such as `graphicx` and well known contrib package such as `stfloats`

If you *only* use the class specific `bioinfo.cls` and `crop.sty` from the zip file, and allow  all of these to come from a current distribution (I compressed them here just to hide them)

```
algorithm.sty.gz      alltt.sty.gz     float.sty.gz     stfloats.sty.gz
algorithm2e.sty.gz    array.sty.gz     flushend.sty.gz  url.sty.gz
algorithmic.sty.gz    caption.sty.gz   graphicx.sty.gz
algorithmicx.sty.gz   chngpage.sty.gz  landscap.sty.gz
algpseudocode.sty.gz  color.sty.gz     natbib.sty.gz
```

Then you get

[image]

Comment: Good catch! Not sure how this will work with their submission system, but this settles it for now. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @BlackBear well if it breaks at their end, tell them several of those packages are mine and if they mail me I will point out that the latex distribution does explicitly say that they should not be distributing undocumented copies of those packages without a full latex distribution.